# Issues fitting logistic GEE model in R

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-estimating-equations

I am trying to predict the probability of having symptoms (binary) after unintentional impact (3 categories: 0, 1, 2+). However, I am having difficulty fitting the logistic GEE model in R.

```
library(geepack)    
form <- MHQ_Symptom_Binary ~ MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category
fit <- geeglm(formula = form, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = new_data, 
              id = Cluster, waves = Visit, corstr = "independence", std.err = "san.se")
```

Data:

```
structure(list(Cluster = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 18L), Visit = c(0, 6, 18, 24, 0, 
6, 12, 18, 24, 0, 6, 18, 24, 0, 6, 9, 0, 9, 0, 0, 12, 18, 24, 
0, 6, 12, 18, 0, 6, 0), MHQ_Symptom_Binary = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("None/Mild", 
"Moderate/Severe/Very Severe"), class = "factor"), MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0", 
"1", "2+"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I keep getting this error:

> using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored�-� not
>   meaningful for factorsError in lm.fit(zsca, qlf(pr2), offset =
>   soffset) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'

I have checked my data and there are no NA/NaN/Inf in the subsetted data I am using- does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: The error is telling you that one of your variables is a factor while the model is expecting it to be numeric.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the **geepack** needs your binary response variable to be `numeric` rather than a `factor`, i.e., the following seems to work:

```
library(geepack)
new_data$MHQ_Symptom_Binary2 <- as.numeric(new_data$MHQ_Symptom_Binary != "None/Mild") 
form <- MHQ_Symptom_Binary2 ~ MHQ_Unintentional_Impacts_Category
fit <- geeglm(formula = form, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = new_data, 
              id = Cluster, waves = Visit, corstr = "independence", std.err = "san.se")
```

Comment: Perfect- thank you so much! Seems strange that geepack has this quirk...